# Why is that my $wpdb->delete value is FALSE, And won't execute properly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm going to delete a row in a table using the $wpdb object

here's my code:

```
function delete_variation($variation_ID){
    $where = array( 
            'ID' => $variation_ID,
            'post_type' => 'product_variation'
        );
    $table_name = 'wp-posts';
    $wpdb->delete( $table_name , $where);
}
```

every arguments are fine, I've got results.. But the

```
$wpdb->delete( $table_name , $where);
```

returned FALSE and won't execute?

no errors has been found, everything seems okay, just that it returned FALSE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `wp_posts` rather than `wp-posts` as your table name.

Comment: Sorry my fault, it's working fine, my code is correct. Just had an issue with this..

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes i found in your code is

1. declare global $wpdb.
2. check for the proper prefix for the table name i.e : wp_posts use  $wpdb->prefix.'posts'

Answer (score 0):

Generally WP uses underscores for table names; so if you're planning on deleting from the main WP posts table, try using `$wpdb->posts` instead for your table name.

Answer (score 0):

try modifying your function as below :

```
function delete_variation($variation_ID){
    global $wpdb;
    $where = array( 
            'ID' => $variation_ID,
            'post_type' => 'product_variation'
        );
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'posts'; // IDEAL WAY FOR TABLE PREFIX
    $wpdb->delete( $table_name , $where);
}
```

Hope this will help you!